# Extract text from a list of Html elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an issue when trying to get the text out of a list of  elements in jquery.

I have a list of  elements in a varible.. What i want is to extract the text from each elements and insert it into a list of strings with comma seperation.

my code:

```
var names = $('input.select:checked').closest('tr').find('.citizen-name');
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                ???;
            }
```

how can i do this?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = $('input.select:checked').closest('tr').find('.citizen-name');
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   arr.push($(names[i]).text());
}
var str = arr.join();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(names[i]).text()` at the place of the question marks would work.
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
$('input.select:checked').closest('tr').find('.citizen-name').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

OR

```
var names = $('input.select:checked').closest('tr').find('.citizen-name');
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    alert(names.eq(i).text());
}
```